# Problems with Tail Recursion and reversing list?

Tags: recursion, prolog, logic, tail

Hello I have a call like this list of digits(436,L).

How can I reverse the list, and make it tail recursive??

```
list_of_digits(0,[]).
list_of_digits(M, [Z|Zx]) :- M > 0 , 
                  MM is floor(M / 10), 
                  Z is M mod 10,        
                  list_of_digits(MM,Zx).
```

Can anyone help me please??

I want to transform my number, in this case 436 into
a List like [4,3,6].

```
I call  ?-  list_of_digits(436,L)
and get 
    L = [6,3,4] ;
    false.
back.
```

Comment: @Boris I want to transform the numeric number 436 into a List, in my example my list is in the wrong order, and not tail recursive, can you explain me, how I can make it tail recursive??

Comment: IMHO it's already tail recursive

Comment: @CapelliC Oh, I only have tried it. Perfekt, and how can i reverse my list??

Comment: @Boris Oh sorry my fault, in my example I get [6,3,4] instead of [4,3,6], I know how i can reverse a list, but i cant merge it. Any suggestion?? I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an accumulator:

```
list_of_digits(X,L) :- lod_acc(X, [], L).
lod_acc(0,R,R).
lod_acc(M,Acc,R) :-
    M > 0, 
    MM is floor(M / 10), 
    Z is M mod 10,        
    lod_acc(MM,[Z|Acc],R).
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way, to deal with negative numbers and with zero itself (a special case):

```
%
% the external/public API predicate.
%
% this handles the special case of zero, which has 1 digit.
% all other cases are handled by the internal worker predicate.
%
digits_in( X , Ds  ) :- int(X) , X > 0 ,               digits_in(X,[],Ds).
digits_in( X , Ds  ) :- int(X) , X < 0 , Y is abs(X) , digits_in(Y,[],Ds).
digits_in( 0 , [0] ) .

%
% the internal/private guts-of-the-operation predicate
%
digits_in( 0 , Ds , Ds ).        % when we hit zero, we're done.
digits_in( X , Ts , Ds ) :-      % otherwise...
  T  is X mod 10 ,               % get the lower order digit via modulus arithmetic
  X1 is X //  10 ,               % get the high order digits via integer division
  digits_in( X1 , [T|Ts] , Ds )  % [tail-]recurse down.
  .
```